For cubic surface, if $\dim(\operatorname{Sing}(X))\geq 1$ then a line is contained a in $\operatorname{Sing}(X)$

Let $X$ to be an irreducible cubic surface in $\mathbb{P}^3_{\mathbb{C}}$. Is it true that if $\dim(\operatorname{Sing}(X))\geq 1$, then a line is contained in $\operatorname{Sing}(X)$? I.e, does a cubic irreducible surface with a singular curve has a double line?

This may be a silly question, and already proved, but I'm searching the literature for an answer to it. It is not clear to me if it is true. Furthermore, I am not sure how would attempt to answer this question myself.

You searching the literature for an answer to what?

@Sasha if this statement holds true. It is not clear to me

See [Miles Reid. Nonnormal del Pezzo surfaces. Publ. Res. Inst. Math. Sci., 30(5):695–727, 1994].

@Sasha sorry, I have made some edits to my initial question. I hope this is more clear

I see the difficulty in stating this problem now. Thanks @Sasha
